# Why don't you calculate individual probabilities in hypothesis testing?

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, hypothesis-testing

Lets say there is a coin being flipped, and someone thinks that the coin is biased so that the probability of getting heads is less than 1/2.

If they flip a coin 10 times, and get heads twice, I understand why hypothesis testing is useful, but I don't understand why to test the hypothesis, we find the probability of getting less than or equal to two heads.

Why don't we just find the probability of getting 2 heads, and decide if that is significantly unlikely or not?

Intuitively, I kind of get that as the number of flips increases, the probability of any single number of heads becomes incredibly small, and so it would be absurd to focus on just that probability, but I still would like some help understanding why we consider the cumulative probabilities.

Thanks

Comment: In practice, you do not know the actual probability. So how do you want to "just find it" ? You could estimate it but that requires a large enough sample anyway.

Comment: I meant we could find the theoretical probability of getting exactly 2 heads, if a fair coin is flipped 10 times , using the binomial probability distribution.

Comment: If we know the coin is fair, yes , we need not toss it. But this is what we want to find out.

Comment: Right - so there's something to be said about the order you do things in. We come up with a hypothesis before collecting data. I find this a bit counterintuitive, as to me, it would be the data that triggers the red flag of "oh, maybe this thing is biased".

Comment: So we toss it often enough to be able to decide with low enough error probability whether the result speaks against the assumed fair coin.

Comment: But I also still don't get how that links to why we want the probability of getting 2, or 1, or 0 heads, instead of just 2.

Comment: How small does the probability need to be in order for the observed outcome to count as evidence against the null hypothesis? For the usual method we have $5\%$ level of confidence, $1\%$ level, $0.5\%$ level, etc., but the probability of exactly $10$ heads is less than $0.018$ for a fair coin, so we obviously can't use $5\%$ (or $10$ heads would be evidence against the coin being fair).

Comment: We should toss the coin anyway at least $200$ times to get enough power for the test.

Comment: So I understand what both of you are saying about the number of trials being important, but I still don't get how this links to my question

Comment: Interpreting low probability events is hard, and working with small samples is hopeless. If $p_H=.5$, then there is only a $.25$ chance of actually seeing $5$ heads out of $10$.  there is a $.41$ chance that you'll see $4$ or $6$.  Would seeing a $4$ or a $6$ cause you to change your sense that the coin was fair?

Comment: And if you use a large sample, then you may as well be continuous...so every event has probability near $0$.

Comment: Maybe the concept of p-values will help you.

Answer (score 2):

A test sees whether the data is too "surprising" for us to still find the null hypothesis credible. The basic idea is we're working out the probability, conditional on the null hypothesis, something at least this surprising would happen. Richard Dawkins once coined the wonderful term [*petwhac*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unweaving_the_Rainbow#Petwhac), "population of events that would have appeared coincidental", to describe the set of events whose probability of containing what actually happened is relevant.

The probability something *exactly* this surprising would happen doesn't tell you anything. It's especially obvious that approach is unworkable for a continuous probability distribution, for which the exactly-this-surprising probability is $0$ for any data. But even in the discrete case, there is e.g. very little chance of exactly a million heads when tossing a fair coin two million times, but you wouldn't claim such an outcome is evidence *against* its being fair.

Comment: Thanks - this sort of helps. I do understand what you said about the discrete case, but I still feel unsatisfied... Can you say a bit more about the petwhac idea please?

Comment: @harpomiel If you would have considered $8$ tails out of $10$ tosses coincidental, you would have felt the same way about $9$ or $10$, _and also $2$ or fewer_. That insight gives us a $2$-tailed probability; and, if you ignore the italicized text, you get a $1$-tailed probability. (Which matters most depends on the type of alternative hypothesis considered.)

Comment: If I considered 8 tails out of 10 coincidental, why would it follow that I feel the same way about 9 or 10?

Comment: @harpomiel Because those are even more at odds with what's average on the null hypothesis.

Comment: When you say coincidental what do you mean? I took it to mean "oh, it's just a coincidence, and not an indication of bias". But I could think "oh, 8 tails is just a coincidence. But hang on, 9 tails is starting to look dodgy... Oh and if I see 10 tails then I don't think its a coincidence anymore."

Comment: @harpomiel Well, I'm leaning on Dawkins's terminology here. By "coincidence", I mean "happened despite being an unlikely event on the null hypothesis". But the point is all events at least as surprising have to be considered as an aggregate.

Comment: Got it! I think I took coincidence to mean the opposite (not surprising). Thank you very much - this helped a lot